# How to fix ls and other basic command not found error in mac-os

Tags: python, bash, macos, terminal

After installation of python in my laptop , I found out . basic bash command like  ls , sudo is not working in my terminal of macbook air. which led problems while the installation of java.
how do I get back original path if I have deleted python

I have deleted python but path still doesn't change but after using this `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`
I can get access of the commands. Is this fine or should I change the path if yes than how ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason why this happened, although its obvious the `PATH` variable is getting overwritten somewhere.

Firstly it would be best to check in `.bash_profile` if something is overwriting your `PATH`.

Just do `open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile` and check where all `PATH` is getting changed and if something is overwriting it, remove that line.

Or simply in order to restore your `PATH`, you can l place:

```
export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

at the end of your `.bash_profile` and save it and reopen terminal.

Comment: After using this export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
,I can access terminal commands otherwise not .

Comment: @akanksha, that's not just with you, everyone needs to have that in path to access the so called terminal commands. To make those changes permanent, all you need to do is add `export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin` to `~/.bash_profile`